# How to dynamically get param from url?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get dynamically value from url param if i have something like this : `?processId=12` or `?groupProcessId=12` ? So what ever i have in url to get it in `queryParams`?

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.processCode = params['dynamicUrlParam'];
   });
```

Sometimes it will be some other value in param not only those two. I cant figure out how i can do that?
Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: You can loop over the keys of `params`

Comment: yes and then what? because key is always different ?

Comment: The keys of `params` are the query paramter names

Comment: Take a look at the `ActivatedRoute`: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let newQueryParams = Object.keys(params);
    let obj = {};
    for(let param of newQueryParams) {
        obj[param] = params[param];
    }
    console.log('newQueryParams', newQueryParams);
    console.log('obj', obj);
})
```